# multiple inputs with same vars

Tags: php, mysql, var

I am trying to send multiple queries from multiple inputs but with same names.

This is the query I need to run

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cv_education VALUES (
    '$id', '$school_name', '$school_desc', '$school_start_date', '$school_end_date'
)";
```

And these are inputs

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="school_name[]" id="exampleInputName2"
    placeholder="Institution name">

<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="school_desc[]"
    placeholder="Tell us about what you did there"></textarea>

<input type="number" id="ed_start_date" name="school_start_date[]"
    placeholder="Date" value="2015">

<input type="number" id="ed_end_date" name="school_end_date[]"
    placeholder="Date" value="2016">
```

But user can add more inputs with same name, how can I run multiple queries from multiple inputs with same name?

I tried "foreach" but it only work for one var.

Comment: **WARNING**: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/). Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? Using prepared statements with placeholder values not only solves this problem but means you won’t spend hours chasing a tiny syntax bug due to incorrect escaping.

Comment: `foreach($arr as $key => $val)`, then use `$other_array[$key]` to access the other parallel arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Creating SQL with user data is very insecure. Don't do it or I'll write to one of your input fields `'); TRUNCATE cv_education; --` and all your data will be gone.

Use PDO or DBAL.

Here is example with PDO:

```
<?php

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass); // change it

$sql = 'INSERT INTO cv_education (' .
       '  school_name, school_desc, school_start_date, school_end_date' .
       ') VALUES (' .
       '  :school_name, :school_desc, :school_start_date, :school_end_date' .
       ')';

$count = count($_POST['school_name']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam('school_name', $_POST['school_name'][$i]);
    $stmt->bindParam('school_desc', $_POST['school_desc'][$i]);
    $stmt->bindParam('school_start_date', $_POST['school_start_date'][$i]);
    $stmt->bindParam('school_end_date', $_POST['school_end_date'][$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```